# Replace countdown with text when it reaches 0?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to replace my countdown with some text after it ends. I can't seem to be able to do this, however.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function() {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + " " + " " + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
        console.log(parseInt(seconds))
        window.localStorage.setItem("seconds", seconds)
        window.localStorage.setItem("minutes", minutes)
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
    sec = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("seconds"))
    min = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("minutes"))

    if (parseInt(min * sec)) {
        var fiveMinutes = (parseInt(min * 60) + sec);
    } else {
        var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5;
    }
    // var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5;
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

Comment: I cant see `some text` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (--timer < 0) {
    display.textContent = "some text";
}
```

Comment: It worked great! Just one question though, will the webpage stay on that text even after it is refreshed? Or will I have to add another line of code to prevent the countdown from restarting?

Comment: @IsmailSaraoui No, it won't stay after refresh. You have to save it localStorage.

Comment: Okay gotcha. Thank you!

Comment: Erh, so I tried to use localStorage to make the text stay after refresh, but I must be doing something wrong because it won't work - it just stops the countdown from happening in the first place. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this:

```
if (--timer < 0) {
    timer = duration;
    display.textContent = minutes + " " + " " + seconds;
}else
    display.textContent = "some text";
```

Comment: Hm... for some reason, that just stopped the countdown from working entirely.

Comment: in that case you could create a flag variable "done" when done is true then you display your text

Comment: Ill try that and see if it works any better. Thank you!